# Can you code a django-fsm transition that targets an arbitrary state?

Tags: python, django, django-models, state-machine

I'm using [django-fsm](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm) on a `state` field (type FSMField) to track sample tubes through a process.  I need to allow some power users to "jump" objects from one state to another, logging and sending notifications when it happens. My question is: **how do I write this transition while avoiding code repeition (i.e. DRY)?**

More details:

I've set `protected=True` on my FSMField: I really like the protection it provides - no other code paths are able to change `state`.

Here's the basics (note: not full code, not expected to work, just to illustrate)

```py
class SampleTube(model.Model):
    state = FSMField(default='new', choices=(...), protected=True)

    @transition(field=state, source='*', target='*', permission='my_app.superpowers')  # <-- problem 1
    def set_state(self, user, new_state):
        assert is_valid_state(new_state)
        log_event(self, user, new_state)
        send_notification(self, self.owner)
        self.state = new_state  # <-- problem 2
```

Problem 1: As I understand it, I can only use a single string value for `target`  ([docs link](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm#usage)).  Fair enough.  I love the fact that calling method models automatically sets the `state`.  So I don't think I can write a transition to an arbitrary state.

Problem 2: If I want to retain `protected=True` (for the reasons above), I can't directly modify the `state` field (raises `AttributeError`, as documented)

Do I have to resort to writing this inside my model class?  Is there some metaprogramming approach that'll keep me DRY?

```py
@transition(field=state, source='*', target='used', permission='myapp.superpowers')
def set_used(self, user):
    # ...

@transition(field=state, source='*', target='received', permission='myapp.superpowers')
def set_received(self, user):
    # ...

#... loads more set_xyz methods that all have the same signature...
```

The reason I want to work this out (other than an appreciation of concise code) is that the number of potential states is quite large (10+).

[edit] Occurs to me that temporarily, explicitly disabling protection on the `state` field inside a `set_state` method might be another way to approach this, if I could work out how...

Comment: Generally speaking, i see no correct answer for your question, b/c question is wrong.

Pythonic approach insist that explicit better than implicit. That's what django-fsm does. As soon as your requirement changed and you need to skip or perform separate action on superuser state change, any generic approach will leads you to huge refactoring.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way that's pythonic and non-repetitive.  I think I am being explicit because the method signature I proposed explicitly has `new_state` as a parameter and explicitly has the permission required in the decorator.  Perhaps I'm missing what you mean here.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the DRY. DRY means for one question give the answer in one place only. In you case you trying to solve N questions in one place (when and how admin can change XXX  to YYY state).

The correct DRY solution would be to have N state transition methods that calls single log/send_notify method.

Answer (score 2):

Although as author of django-fsm I highly don't recommend use your approach, I think finally it could leads you to `if-elif` trash inside `set_state` function, I could suggest, not to implement it as model method.

Instead just make a regular function, and update db state directly.

`def set_state(tube, new_state):
    SampleTube.objects.filter(pk=tube.pk).update(state=new_state);`

Comment: Thank you - that's good advice, I appreciate your experience and will try to do things this way.  One challenge doing it this way is that in-memory instances don't receive the update to their `state` property, and I can't call `refresh_from_db()` on a model with protected fields.Is there a solution to my original subquestion (see the edit at the bottom): can I explicitly, temporarily disable protection on a field?

Comment: No, there is no non-hacky way to disable field protection in django_fsm. This feature is missing b/c having `set_state()` is not explicit and not follows fsm paradigm.